# Find min and max value of array

Tags: javascript, for-loop, numbers, max, min

I have previously created an array of random numbers from 0 to 100 and am required to create a function that gets the minimum and maximum number from the array. I can't understand the solution to it;

```js
let randomNumbers = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  randomNumbers.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 100));
}

console.log(...randomNumbers);

function getMaxMin(numbers) { // when declaring numbers in the brackets here, what are we doing? Max and min are defined later so does returning min and max as done later push two values to the function?
  let max = numbers[0];
  let min = numbers[0];

  /*for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++) { // why - 1?
      if (numbers[i] > max){
          max = numbers[i]
      }
      
      if (numbers[i]< min) {
          min = numbers[i]
      }
  }*/

  for (let number of numbers) {
    max = number > max ? number : max;
    min = number < min ? number : min;
  }

  return { max, min };
}

console.log(getMaxMin(randomNumbers));
```

I have included some questions in the code, but to be honest I am struggling with functions and finding the right way to ask about what I dont understand. The (numbers) in the function, ive seen  different things inputted in these brackets but dont understand what part this part of the code plays. If someone could provide a bit of a breakdown to each step in the process I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: where do you get the solution from?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp

Comment: From a course that I am on

Answer (score 1):

The `numbers` part of `function getMaxMin(numbers)` is an argument the `getMaxMin` function accepts. This variable will only be accessible within the `getMaxMin` function scope.

In the global scope at the bottom, when calling `getMaxMin(randomNumbers)`, you are passing the value of `randomNumbers` into the function and then the function executes with that value as the value of the local variable `numbers`.

The part of the function:

```js
for (let number of numbers) {
  max = number > max ? number : max;
  min = number < min ? number : min;
}
```

can be read like this:
"For each `number` in the iterable `numbers`, take the following actions:

1. set the value of `max` to `number` IF the `number` is greater than `max`, otherwise set the value of `max` to `max` (do nothing)
2. set the value of `min` to `number` IF the `number` is less than `min`, otherwise set the value of `min` to `min` (do nothing)
   "

Check out:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions

Comment: Thanks both, I am starting to understand it more but struggling with the min and max part of the code, i see max = if the value of number is more than the value of max then return the value of number, if not max... but where is max declared? Likewise with min I dont understand where this has been declared to be able to compare to it. I read it as we are declaring max and min to be two number values, creating a for loop that states if the number is larger than itself display that number, I hope you see how I am viewing it as this?

Comment: yes `max` and `min` are being declared with the `let` keyword at the top of the function, setting their initial values both equal to the first number in the array.

Answer (score 1):

The line you commented `function getMaxMin(numbers) {` here `numbers` is the parameter of the `getMaxMin` function. Later when you call this function inside `console.log()` like this `console.log(getMaxMin(randomNumbers));` there the `randomNumbers` is the actual value that is passed as a parameter to the `getMaxMin` function. And this `randomNumbers` is the array of random numbers you generated earlier.
So, in the function declaration line (your commented line), you are not passing anything actually. You are just given a name of the parameter. Which means, if something is passed into this function as a parameter then inside this function that parameter will be recognised as `numbers`.

Answer (score 0):

> when declaring numbers in the brackets here, what are we doing?

We are passing the `numbers` array to the function `getMaxMin` as a parameter.

> Max and min are defined later so does returning min and max as done later push two values to the function?

At the end, we have successfully found the min and max, so we are returning that in a `object`.

> why - 1?

As far as I think it `numbers.length - 1` is a mistake. By doing this, we are not comparing the last element of array. And it may be possible that that is the largest/smallest element.
If still `-1` has to be present then we can modify the condition as such

```
for (let i = 0; i <= numbers.length - 1; i++)
```

To understand the logic of how this is done:
We take two `variables`,  `max` and `min`. We initialize both of them to be equal to first element of array.
As we iterate through the array, we check at every step if the current number is bigger/smaller then `max` or `min`.
If it is bigger, we make `max` equal to that.
If it is smaller, we make `min` equal to that.

Refer these links for more understanding:

- Function parameters:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function
- Ternary Operator in Javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 0):

For me, it looks like an error, to iterate without the last element of the array until this element is the start value for comparing.

```
let max = numbers[numbers.length - 1];         // use last
let min = max;                                 // use last

for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++) { // iterate without last
    if (numbers[i] > max) max = numbers[i];
    if (numbers[i] < min) min = numbers[i];
}
```

A better approach by keeping the block of the `for` statement, you be to iterate from index 1 until smaller length of the array and taking the first element as start value.

```
let max = numbers[0];                          // use first
let min = max;                                 // use first

for (let i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {     // iterate without first
    if (numbers[i] > max) max = numbers[i];
    if (numbers[i] < min) min = numbers[i];
}
```

---

Just for completeness, by [spreading `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the elements of an array or other [iterables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#Built-in_iterables), along with [`Math.min`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) or [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max), you get the wanted result without manually iterating.